# Correct typing for createSelector callbacks arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am studying the documentation for redux-toolkit-query and there is an example:

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { selectUserById } from '../users/usersSlice'
import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../api/apiSlice'

export const UserPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { userId } = match.params

  const user = useSelector(state => selectUserById(state, userId))

  const selectPostsForUser = useMemo(() => {
    const emptyArray = []
    // Return a unique selector instance for this page so that
    // the filtered results are correctly memoized
    return createSelector(
      res => res.data,
      (res, userId) => userId,
      (data, userId) => data?.filter(post => post.user === userId) ?? emptyArray
    )
  }, [])

  // Use the same posts query, but extract only part of its data
  const { postsForUser } = useGetPostsQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: result => ({
      // We can optionally include the other metadata fields from the result here
      ...result,
      // Include a field called `postsForUser` in the hook result object,
      // which will be a filtered list of posts
      postsForUser: selectPostsForUser(result, userId)
    })
  })

  // omit rendering logic
}
```

I am trying to rewrite this example using TypeScript, and I cannot understand how to correctly infer the types for the arguments of the callback functions in `createSelector`. As `result` from `selectFromResult` receives the type `UseQueryStateDefaultResult`, which I do not know how to get.

I have not found an answer in the documentation or anywhere else. I can just pass `result.data` to selectors  and type data in `createSelector` but I want follow examples as close as possible like in original documentation and want to know the 'right way'.